# Display TFS test cases in TreeView based on plain text 'Folder' property

Tags: c#, tfs, treeview

The test cases used in our department were migrated into TFS from SpiraTeam. SpiraTeam allowed the test cases to be stored in a folder hierarchy, e.g.

Ordering/Order & Stock/Send an Order/Test 1: Send a normal order

TFS does not support this hierarchy so, during the migration process, we copied the folder hierarchy of each test as plain text and now store it in a plain-text field in the TFS work item called 'Folder'.

I'm working on a small C# app that will allow test cases to be viewed in this hierarchy and edited from it.

I plan to build a TreeView from the hierarchy to display the test cases.

I have all the functionality to retrieve the test cases, and currently store them in a WorkItemStore within the app, but I have two problems:

1. How do I present this information in a TreeView? I understand I will have to use a recursive algorithm, but any research on this topic brings back instructions on how to build a TreeView from actual Windows directories, rather than the plain-text field I need to use. I have started by using the .Split method to split the 'Folder' field into an array of strings.
2. Once I get the information into the TreeView, how would I navigate to the correct test case in the WorkItemStore based on the selection from the TreeView, since the TreeView nodes appear to be based on strings? Using the above path as an example, I would like a more elegant solution than selecting the work item from the store WHERE [Title] = 'Test 1: Send a normal order'.

Perhaps a solution to my second question will dictate how I implement this, and my first question may be irrelevant.

Some pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example program that can be run in LinqPad. It takes a WorkItem (in this case is a class I created) and traverses down the Path after splitting it by `/`, creating Nodes down the line as it goes, if it finds a node in the same collection with the same text, it uses that instead.

```
void Main()
{
    //Create a treeview with a root node.
    TreeView tv = new TreeView();
    tv.ShowNodeToolTips = true; //Turn on tooltips for this demo.
    tv.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Root"));

    //These may need ordering by path before you start.
    var tfsTestCases = new[]
    {
        new WorkItem { Path = "Module/Feature1/SubFeature1/Test1", WorkItemId = 1, },
        new WorkItem { Path = "Module/Feature1/SubFeature1/Test2", WorkItemId = 2, },
        new WorkItem { Path = "Module/Feature1/SubFeature2/Test1", WorkItemId = 3, },
        new WorkItem { Path = "Module/Feature1/SubFeature2/Test2", WorkItemId = 4, },
        new WorkItem { Path = "Module/Feature2/SubFeature1/Test1", WorkItemId = 5, },
        new WorkItem { Path = "Module/Feature2/SubFeature1/Test2", WorkItemId = 6, },
    };

    //Looping through the test cases...
    foreach (var testCase in tfsTestCases)
    {
        //Start at the root of the tree for each work item.
        TreeNode lastNode = tv.Nodes[0];

        //Loop through each part of the path and create a new node.
        //Use the NodeCollection from the one we just created each time through the loop.
        //This allows the next iteration to "walk down" as it goes.
        foreach (var part in testCase.Path.Split('/'))
            lastNode = AddTreeNode(lastNode.Nodes, part);

        //Set the Tag on the last node in the loop, this is the one with the actual Test Case.
        //You can reference the Tag property of "tv.SelectedNode" to get access to the Work Item. If the Tag is null, then it's not a Test Case.
        lastNode.Tag = testCase;
        lastNode.ToolTipText = testCase.WorkItemId.ToString();  //Set for this DEMO.
    }
    //Display the tree.
    tv.Dump();
}

TreeNode AddTreeNode(TreeNodeCollection nodes, String path)
{
    //Try and find a node in the collection matching the specified pathPath.
    var node = nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Where(node => node.Text == path).SingleOrDefault();
    //If it's not found, create it and add it to the collection of nodes we just searched.
    if (node == null)
    {
        node = new TreeNode(path);
        nodes.Add(parentNode);
    }
    //We need this later, so pass it back.
    return node;
}

class WorkItem
{
    public String Path { get; set; }
    public Int32 WorkItemId { get; set; }
    //etc.
}
```